# Golang variable inside json field tag

Tags: go

Is there a way to change structs field tag dynamicly?

```
key := "mykey"

// a struct definition like
MyStruct struct {
    field `json:key` //or field `json:$key` 
}

// I want the following output
{
     "mykey": 5
}
```

Couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Answer (score 5):

You can customise how a type is marshaled by implementing the [`json.Marshaler` interface](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler).  This overrides the default behaviour of introspecting the fields of structs.

For this particular example, you could do something like:

```
func (s MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        key: s.field,
    }
    return json.Marshal(data)
}
```

Here I'm constructing a `map[string]interface{}` value that represents what I want in the JSON output and passing it to `json.Marshal`.

You can test out this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/oTmuNMz-0e

Comment: this method overwrites the existing field tags.

Comment: Yes.  It replaces the default marshalling (including parsing of struct field tags).  But that's what you'll have to live with if you want what you asked for.